# NullPointerException when i run my project

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, argumentnullexception

i have a problem with my code, this is error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object
>   reference

there is no error in code, but when run there is a null exception error, I don't know where is null, this is error

> at
>   com.mulazi.submission2.MovieListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MovieListAdapter.java:57)
>            at com.mulazi.submission2.MovieListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MovieListAdapter.java:20)

this is my code

```
package com.mulazi.submission2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.mulazi.submission2.R;
import com.mulazi.submission2.DetailActivity;
import com.mulazi.submission2.Movie;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MovieListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieListAdapter.MovieViewHolder>  {
    private List<Movie> movieList;

    public MovieListAdapter() {
        movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void add(Movie item) {
        movieList.add(item);
        notifyItemInserted(movieList.size() - 1);
    }

    public void addAll(List<Movie> movieList) {
        for (Movie movie : movieList) {
            add(movie);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_movie, parent, false);
        return new MovieViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MovieViewHolder holder,final int position) {
        final Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(holder.itemView.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", movie);
                holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.moviePhoto.setImageResource(movie.getPhoto());
        holder.movieName.setText(movie.getName());
        holder.movieDate.setText(movie.getDate());
        holder.movieDesc.setText(movie.getDescription());
        holder.movieDuration.setText(movie.getDuration());
        holder.movieDirector.setText(movie.getDirector());
        holder.movieGenre.setText(movie.getGenre());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movieList.size();
    }

    static class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView moviePhoto;
        TextView movieName;
        TextView movieDesc;
        TextView movieDate;
        TextView movieDuration;
        TextView movieDirector;
        TextView movieGenre;

        MovieViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            moviePhoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_photo);
            movieName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            movieDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_description);
            movieDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_date);
            movieDirector = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_director);
            movieDuration = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_duration);
            movieGenre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_genre);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope anyone helps me resolve this error,

Comment: The error is at line 57 `holder.moviePhoto.setImageResource(movie.getPhoto());`. Furthermore, the error says you are calling setImageResource(...) on a null object, indicating that holder.moviePhoto is null.

Comment: @KevinBarron so what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your layout file. Very likely you forget to put img_photo in your layout:

```
moviePhoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_photo);
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong between xml and id